# what have i done wrong trying to call the model with form value

Tags: forms, scala, playframework-2.0

This:

```
  def signup = Action { implicit request =>
    signupForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.login(loginForm,formWithErrors)),
      signer => 
        Signup.insert(signer)
        Redirect(routes.Application.login)
    )
  }
```

give me this error (value Redirect is not a member of Int possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value Redirect'?)

if i comment out Signup.insert(signer) its fine but i want it to call that...

but when i use this its fine:

```
def save = IsAuthenticated { username => implicit request =>
    User.findByEmail(username).map { user => 
      personForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.person_views.createForm(formWithErrors, user)),
      person => {
        Person.insert(person)
        Redirect(routes.Persons.list()).flashing("success" -> "success")
      }
    )
    //}.getOrElse(Forbidden)
    }.getOrElse(Forbidden)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def signup = Action { implicit request =>
    signupForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.login(loginForm,formWithErrors)),
      signer => {
        Signup.insert(signer)
        Redirect(routes.Application.login)
      }
    )
}
```

Basically, the way it was written before was like you were writing:

```
Signup.insert(signer) Redirect(routes.Application.login)
```

Which means, when the `insert` is done, apply the `Redirect` method on the result, the result of the `insert`, I assume, is an `Int`, hence the error message:

> value Redirect is not a member of Int possible cause